# controller does not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function, routes, controller

I used 2 routes for calling sam function

1. Route::get('/sami', 'App\Http\Controller\CommentController@sam');
2. Route::get('sami',[CommentController::class, 'sam']);

but still got this error -
"Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controller\CommentController] does not exist."

Comment: can you post full controller or namespace used in it

Answer (score 1):

did u put :

```
      use App\Http\Controller\CommentController ;
```

you need to add it in the route